# import list of domains into recon-ng

Tags: tools, dns-domain, reconnaissance

Is there a way to add domains into recon-ng from a text file (newline delimited)? I've tried comma delimiting entries but reco-ng takes the comma as part of the domain.
At the moment I am doing:

```
for line in $(cat domains.txt); do printf "add domains\n%s\n" $line; done
```

in a shell then pasting the resultant output into recon-ng.
It's a little kludgy but doesn't take too long and it works.
Is there an official way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recon-ng already supports import of external data (by newlines) with the SOURCE variable. SOURCE should be available via most plugins, including the domain ones you are interested in.

Check the wiki -- https://bitbucket.org/LaNMaSteR53/recon-ng/wiki/Usage%20Guide -- which includes information on using the SOURCE variables for data from the local filesystem.

There are also the `import/csv_file` and `import/list` modules in recon-ng which will push your data into the recon-ng database.

The method for creating a workspace and using `add domains` to add domains to that workspace's database can be seen in this blog post -- https://www.stevencampbell.info/2016/10/passive-information-gathering/ -- after which you can see the domains along with IP-address data by way of `show hosts`. This appears to be the way that you are adding domains, which is one way of doing this.

Once a domain plugin is run, or if a workspace is created and domains are added -- as long as you see your domain via `show hosts`, then the recon-ng database (usually best performed per workspace) can be modified just like any sqlite3 database. For more information on where recon-ng places these sqlite3 databases on your local filesystem as well as other tips and tricks, see this blog post --https://www.codemetrix.net/practical-osint-recon-ng/